# Use of Indefinite Articles(a,an)

Tags: word-usage, indefinite-article

Consider the following sentences:

> I am staying in ***a*** hotel nearby.
>
> I am staying in ***an*** hotel nearby.

I know that both are correct. But I would like to know why? I do not see any proper reason for the second one as the 'h' is not silent as in French.
So, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style guides are divided on 'a' vs 'an' before a silent 'h'.

The general rule would be to follow the pronunciation of the dialect you are writing for.

If your audience would drop the aitch when speaking, use 'an'.

Comment: Like I said, in all the various dialects that exist, 'h' isn't silent in hotel! (well maybe in a few, but not in the common ones, like British, American, Australian, Indian etc.)

Comment: There absolutely are regional dialects that would pronounce hotel with a silent h. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_fricatives_and_affricates#H-dropping_and_h-adding

Answer (score 0):

In written English, I think it's always ...

> I'm staying in **a** hotel nearby.

Nevertheless, in any dialect (not sure AmE or BrE), if the initial /h/ is pronounced as a vowel, it will be...

> I'm staying in **an** hotel nearby.

Comment: I am sure of both being right, I have the 'Oxford A:Z of Grammar' book which says so.

Comment: That is the problem. Hotel has a the 'h' pronounced both in American and British dialects. Then why does the book say that both are right?

Comment: It's an old-fashioned rule. Some British dialects would say "an 'otel."

Comment: Any reason for, as you say, 'dropping the h' ?

Comment: Some commentary on the history of h-dropping: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23396/is-the-history-of-h-dropping-in-english-in-any-way-related-to-the-silent-h-of-fr/23475#23475

Comment: By "pronounced as a vowel", do you mean "not pronounced at all"?  (Phonetically speaking, /h/ is always a vowel, but we treat it as though it's a consonant.)