# 'An' heroine - is this correct usage?

Tags: articles

Chapter 1 of Jane Austen's 'Northanger Abbey' starts with:

> No one who had ever seen Catherine Morland in her infancy would have supposed her born to be an heroine.

Any other place anyone can point me to that uses 'an' heroine?

EDIT: The question is not about use of aspirate that some answers have pointed out. I am looking for another book example (preferably non-Jane Austen) where the same usage (an heroine) was made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [**Is it 'an hotel' or 'a hotel'**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/282771/is-it-an-hotel-or-a-hotel) .... also [**use of indefinite articles a/an**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19360/use-of-indefinite-articlesa-an) and [**use of the aspirate after the indefinite article**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37551/use-of-the-aspirate-after-the-indefinite-article) among others

Comment: @Void : I understand the use of aspirate in this case. I am looking for another book example where 'an' heroine was used.

Comment: Downvote and close-vote based on lack of research. [A Google Books search for "an heroine"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+heroine%22) provides several examples; the first few are analyses that quote the Austin book you mentioned, but scrolling down the page reveals other uses from the 1700s and 1800s.

Comment: I’m not sure I’d be allowed to quote the passage that uses it from [*Fanny Hill* in 1749.](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/25305/25305-h/25305-h.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a difference of dialect.  People say “a” before a breathy H but “an” before a silent H.  Jane Austen spoke a dialect where the H in heroine was silent.  I personally would say, “a heroine,” but “an herb,” or “a house” but “an hour.”

That said, “a heroine” is much more common today, and “an hero” would make me think of an offensive meme, rather than the older British writers who used it.

Comment: Any other written (meaning book) example of such dialect that said 'an heroine'?

Comment: @sm535 [This 1763 translation of *Jerusalem Delivered: An Heroic Poem*](https://www.peterharrington.co.uk/jerusalem-delivered-an-heroic-poem-146225.html) is one early example, but I still run into “an heroic” occasionally in modern times.

Comment: Rudyard Kipling’s “Gunga Din” is a work that tries to represent the dialect of the narrator by replacing all silent H’s with apostrophes. So that gives you a good idea of which H’s were silent: generally unstressed initial syllables, explaining “an heROic” but “a HEro.”

Comment: Kipling's representations of soldiers' speech (uneducated men who drop their h's) is not relevant. I'm sure Jane Austen didn't speak like that! Certain English words have preserved the unaspirated 'h' ('herb' in American English but not in British); 'heroine' must have been one of those in Austen's time.

Comment: @KateBunting Certainly, Kipling was representing an accent different from his own, or Jane Austen’s, who was from a different social class and time period than either. It’s a rare example of someone consistently marking which H’s were silent and which ones weren’t.